# What should I use, UITableView or UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to make a Google+ type card list (the home page in the ios app) on iPhone. I am confused that, should I use a UITableView with custom cells or a single column UICollectionView with custom cells?

Edit: I am concerned about performance and ease of development. But I think I got my answer as
I found UITableViewCell to easy to customize and use.

Comment: Look at this tutorial, http://www.raywenderlich.com/49311/advanced-table-view-animations-tutorial-drop-in-cards for Google+ type card list

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, it really solves my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `UITableView` would work better for you.
In order to use `UITableView`, your class should conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` Protocol.

Comment: Agreed, for G+ like apps you can go for some custom table views other than UITableview which make your coding easier